# Strict-transport-security header not found for the base domain

Tags: java, azure, spring-boot, hsts

I have a spring boot application and I want to enable the HSTS over my domain (say https:example.com).
I wrote the script in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. The code snippet is shown below.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off           
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.TRACE, "/**").denyAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
            http
                .antMatcher("/**").httpBasic()
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity()
                .includeSubDomains(true)
                .maxAgeInSeconds(31536000);
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }
```

The deployment of the spring boot application happened in the Azure cloud. After the deployment, I'm not seeing the HSTS header when I hit the base domain.
But I can see the header when hitting the entire URL (say https://example.com/questions/ask).
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `antMatcher` in the configuration of basic authentication etc. Also does the main URL `/` actually go to the application/Spring Boot is is that a static landing page served from something else?

Comment: Does you mean removing the below code
.antMatcher("/**").httpBasic() from the configuration

Comment: No, only the `antMatcher` part of that line.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't catch it.. Could you please edit and upload here. Thanks!

Comment: Chagne `antMatcher("/**").httpBasic()` to `httpBasic()`.

Comment: Updated and deployed again.Still no luck

Comment: Then again I'll ask the question is that page being served by this application or is that a static page not served by your application? If this is a welcome-page for your app server (you mentioned deployed, so that triggers me for an app-server) that will not pass through this filter chain afaik and thus it doesn't apply.

Comment: That page is served by the application because I did the change " .antMatchers(HttpMethod.TRACE, "/**").denyAll()" in that page and is working as expected

Comment: A TRACE request isn't a GET request. The TRACE isn't handled by your server so it passes on the GET can be handled by your server. And this isn't an answer to the question, is this a welcome-file (i.e. `index.jsp`) served by the server (even if it is packaged in your application the server will send it) or by your application. It still looks like the server is doing this and not your application.